# Disable CKEditor Context Menu Client-Side

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am in an online class that happens to use CKEditor 4.4 for posting.  They use CKEDitor's context menu, which disables the Chrome's spell check, which is a major problem for me.  I have no control over their configuration.  I am trying to run javascript in the console after the page is loaded that will disable their context menu.  I have found:

CKEDITOR.config.removePlugins='contextmenu';

But this does nothing because the editor is already loaded by the time I can run it. I cannot seem to get the editor to reload itself in-line with the new settings.  Any ideas?

Comment: In what way does it disable spell check? If you just want to see suggestions for a word, all you need to do is hold *Ctrl* when right-clicking.

Comment: @fstanis Yes, I am referring to its override of Chrome's default context menu.  I could hit CTRL during right-click but that is rather annoying with large posts.  I was hoping to be able to restore Chrome's default context menu via JS.  That way I would only need to run it once on each page load, or maybe I could throw it into an extension so I would never have to deal with this problem again.  It seems that this should be possible.

Answer (score 2):

If the page has been already loaded and the editor has been created you can destroy it and create it again. 
You should check if they use any special configuration while creating the editor and reuse that same configuration but adding "contextmenu" to the list of plugins to remove.

Generic code:

```
for(name in CKEDITOR.instances)
{
    CKEDITOR.instances[name].destroy(true);
}
CKEDITOR.replaceAll()
```

If the textarea is named for example "content"

```
CKEDITOR.instances.content.destroy(true);
CKEDITOR.replace("content");
```